# XMLUnit diff with HTML files

Tags: java, html, xml, xhtml, xmlunit

I am trying to use XMLUnit's diff with two HTML documents. To do this, I convert them to strings and then construct a diff object from the two strings.

However, this throws the following SAXException:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:177: The element type "br" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</br>".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "br" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</br>".
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.buildDocument(XMLUnit.java:383)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.XMLUnit.buildDocument(XMLUnit.java:370)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.<init>(Diff.java:101)
    at org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff.<init>(Diff.java:93)
    at controllers.Api.diffUrls(Api.java:292)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$8$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(routes_routing.scala:165)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$8$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(routes_routing.scala:165)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183)
    at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:278)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

So therefore I need to convert this HTML to valid XML. I see that XMLUnit offers HTMLDocumentBuilder which seems to provide a way to do this, but only for XPath evaluation. What is a simple way to convert to valid HTML so I can do an XMLUnit diff?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HTMLDocumentBuilder`'s `parse` method to create a `Document` from your HTML input.  `Diff` and the other parts of XMLUnit's difference engine will happily work with `Document`s.

Please note that `HTMLDocumentBuilder` is a bit of a hack and you are probably better suited with a library that specializes in HTML => XML conversions like jTidy.